# What does a \" do in php?

Tags: php, html

I am very new to PHP and HTML, and I came across some code that has a `\"` where a select name is defined.

```
<select name=\"table\" ...
```

My question is: what is that doing?

Thank you.

Comment: It's an escape character.

Comment: http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @CrayonViolent — It probably isn't a regular expression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an escape character. It's used to ensure that the next character is not treated as code, but as part of the string.

In this case, it means that the " is part of the string, and doesn't signify the end of the string within the code.

For example, if I want to put this inside of a string...

> He said "shut up"...

I'd write something like this...

```
$str = "He said \"shut up\"...";
```

The backslash can also be used for special "sequences", which insert special characters. For example, if I want to insert a newline into the string, I'd use the `\n` escape sequence. Or, if I want a full CRLF, I'd use `\r\n` to insert both the carriage return (`\r`) and the line feed (`\n`) together. There are many escape sequences, most of which are described [here, in the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 5):

It escapes the double quote. Consider this:

```
echo "Hello world, John said "Hello world!"";
```

This would not evaluate, because John's quotewould get processed by PHP as syntax, so you use the escape character `\` to skip it:

```
echo "Hello world, John said \"Hello world!\"";
```

This is only applicable to double quotes, but would also be used for single quotes in the same way:

```
echo 'John said \'Hello!\'';
```

... but this would be fine:

```
echo "John said 'Hello'";
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\` is used as an *escape character* in many programming langauges, such as PHP, Java, and C#.  The escape character allows the usage of special characters, such as `"` and various special "values" such as `\n` for a new line.

[Here is a reference to Escape sequences in PHP for further reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Answer (score 1):

The `\` is an escape character. In your example, you are outputting HTML, and need to include the quotes, so you use the `\` to ignore the quotes and thus create an HTML statement that looks like `<select="table"...`